# Add sheet in axlsx

Tags: ruby, axlsx

I try to add sheet to existing xlsx file through axlsx gem.
Is it possible to open the file and add the sheet ?

Everytime i change the sheet name the sheet is getting overwritten with new sheet. not able to find how `p` should be initialized to the existing object instead of new.

```
filename='output_file.xlsx'

p = Axlsx::Package.new

f = File.open(filename, 'a+')

ws = p.workbook.add_worksheet

ws.name="sheetone"
```

Comment: I think you cannot open existing files using Axlsx, you can use roo instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add a sheet to the existing workbook, you can do like this

```
p.workbook.add_sheet(name: what_ever_name_you_want) do |sheet|
// your can manipulate how ever you want
end
```

if you want to save it in a file

```
p.serialize(fullpath_of_your_file)
```

Comment: this overwrites the whole file with the new sheet. all the previous content on the sheet getting erased.